# Gui in Python 3.3?

Tags: python, python-3.3

I would like to make a menu for my program in the form of a GUI where the user can select what they want by clicking on a box instead of typing in a number / letter. This is what i got so far:

```
while True:
    encrypt = False
    decrypt = False
    viewz = False
    errorz = False
    inp = input("Do you want to [E]ncode, [D]ecode, [V]iew Code or [EX]it:")
    inp = inp.lower()
    if (inp != "e"  and inp != "d" and inp != "encode" and inp != "decode" and inp != "v" and inp != "view code" ):
        print("Input error")
        print()
        continue
    if inp == "e" or inp == "encode":
        encrypt = True
    if inp == "d" or inp == "decode":
        decrypt = True
```

Comment: did nor know how to add code sorry

Comment: Well, there're several graphic libraries. Tkinter is the built in one, and the simplest one.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a few observations: Currently, you can't exit from your script (`"ex(it)"` isn't among the options). And you can clean this long query up: `if inp not in ("e", "d", "encode", "decode", "v", "view"):` and, correspondingly `if inp in ("e", "encode"):` later on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tkinter example for python 3.3 on windows. Not entirely sure where you were going with this but hope it helps.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

encrypt = False
decrypt = False
viewz = False
errorz = False # Not sure why you had this, but included it as it may be handy for you

def encode():
    encrypt = True
    window.destroy()

def decode():
    decrypt =True
    window.destroy()

def viewcode():
    viewz = True # I think this is what you were going to do here?
    window.destroy()

def Exit():
    window.destroy() # Assuming you want the exit button to exit the tk window

label = tk.Label(text = "Do you want to:")
encodebutton = tk.Button(text = "Encode", command = encode)
decodebutton = tk.Button(text = "Decode", command = decode)
viewcodebutton = tk.Button(text = "View Code", command = viewcode)
exitbutton = tk.Button(text = "Exit", command = Exit)
# Theres heaps more you can do with tkinter, google it and give it a go it's heaps of   fun.
label.pack()
encodebutton.pack()
decodebutton.pack()
viewcodebutton.pack()
exitbutton.pack()

window.mainloop()
# After this you go on with your code :p
```